# How to execute linux terminal command diff within a program using exec( )

Tags: c, linux, unix

I attempted using `execl("diff", "diff", "file1.txt", "file2.txt");`,
but it failed because the first argument is suppose to be the path of this program. What is the file path of `diff`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `whereis` command find the command path.

```
rajalakshmi@stack-$ 
rajalakshmi@stack-$ whereis diff
       diff: /usr/bin/diff /usr/bin/X11/diff /usr/share/man/man1/diff.1.gz
rajalakshmi@stack-$
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `execlp` which takes as argument the **name** of the command and use the `PATH` environment variable to locate the corresponding executable. `execl` takes the **path** of the executable.